# Importing a PSD into After Effects, can't retain the layer sizes

Tags: after-effects

I'd like to know how can I import a PSD file into AE keeping the size of the PS layers. When I import my PSD as a composition all layers are created with the size of the composition itself and don't fit to the original size of each shape (image) contained in them, although I'm using the "preserve layer sizes" option. So, the images keep their size, but the layer where they are contained in the composition shows a lot of useles transparency that, besides, becomes an annoyance when I need to resize the layer.

If I open the PSD with GIMP (and if I'm not wrong) I'd say that I can see the layers fit exactly the size of the pixels and alpha channel, not the whole image, as it should be.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong in PS?

Thanks in advance.